# Wrapper function for usage of gdal_calc.py in R

Tags: r, geospatial, gdal, rgdal

R offers wrappers for gdal libraries with the `gdalUtils` package. I would like to use the gdal_calc.py funcion for raster calculations, however, I did not find information about this specific function in the package. I created my own wrapper function which works, however often not 100% perfect and only on linux. It is also less flexible than the original (see below if interested). Is there another implementation in R?

```
f.gdal.calc<-function(path.in.r.1,
                      #r1.band=1,
                      path.in.r.2,
                      # r2.band=1,
                      path.out.r,
                      my.fun="A*B",#defaults to multiplication
                      r.datatype="Float32",
                      cachemax=2000, 
                      overwrite=FALSE, # caution, can destroy data
                      printcommand=FALSE,# should the commad be printed prior to execution? Can help debugging 
                      bigtiff=F,
                      compression=F) 
{gdalcommand<-paste("gdal_calc.py ",
                    "-A ",path.in.r.1,
                    # " --allBands A ",
                    #"--A_band=",r1.band,
                    " -B ",path.in.r.2,
                    #"--b_band=",r2.band,
                    " --outfile=",path.out.r,
                    " --calc=",shQuote(my.fun,type = "cmd"),# supply function as character like "A+B"
                    " --type ",r.datatype,
                    ifelse(overwrite==TRUE,paste(" --overwrite"),paste("")),
                    ifelse(compression==TRUE,paste(" --co COMPRESS=LZW"),paste("")), #should not be enabled when creating bigtiffs
                    ifelse(bigtiff==TRUE,paste(" --co BIGTIFF=YES"),paste("")),
                    sep=""
                     ) 
if(printcommand==T){print(gdalcommand)}
system(gdalcommand)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the developers, no python based gdal functions are implemented so far in `gdalUtils`. Therefore, if you would like to use `gdal_calc` for raster calculations in R you would need to create your own wrapper function similar to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the ´rast_math´ & ´gdal_calc´ function inside the ´agroEcoTradeoff´ R package:

https://rdrr.io/github/marcusspiegel/agroEcoTradeoff/src/R/rast_math.R

Hope it is useful!